# List<List<>>.Contains() not working

Tags: c#, list, contains

I have the following code:

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
list.Add(new List<int> { 0, 1 });

if (list.Contains(new List<int> { 0, 1 }))      // false
  ...
```

I'm trying to check whether the list contains {0,1}, but the condition is false (I don't know why, maybe because the 'new' keyword).
If this is not the proper way, I'd like to know how to check that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`List<T>.Contains` calls the `Equals()` method to compare objects.
Since the inner `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals`, you get reference equality.

You can fix this by creating a custom `IEqualityComparer<List<T>>` that compares by value and passing it to `Contains()`.

You can also just use LINQ:

```
if (list.Any(o => o.SequenceEqual(new[] { 0, 1 }))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking to see if `list` contains List #2 you've made, when you added List #1. Contains ordinarily checks to see if the object is contained by using the Equals method, but List does not override this method. This means that in this case, it does a reference comparison.

It is clear from your code that the two will not refer to the same List, even if their values are the same.

Comment: Well no, Contains checks using Equals... but that isn't overridden in this case.

Comment: Equals isn't the same thing as ==. You can't *override* operators.

Comment: ARGH! Apparently I know just enough C# to get myself in trouble.

Comment: Righto, that's more like it :)

Answer (score 2):

[Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

The following code shows why your code doesn't work:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 0, 1 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 0, 1 };

Console.WriteLine(list1.Equals(list2)); // prints false
```

`List<T>` itself does not implement `Equals`, so it compares using `object.Equals`, which checks on reference equality, which do not match in above and your case.

You could for example create an own implementation that extends `List<List<int>>` and override the `Equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

The contains is checking references, not the contents on the contained list. The following would work

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
var b = new List<int> { 0, 1 }
list.Add(b);

if (list.Contains(b))...
```