# Comparing Lists of Lists of strings where order doesn't matter

Tags: c#, list, nested, compare

The idea behind my CheckOrder() method is to compare two Lists of string Lists by seeing if the first List contains a List from the second List. If so, it removes the List from the second List, so that it cannot be compared against again. It repeats this until there are no more Lists in the second List to compare against, or it determines that the Lists of Lists are inequal.

To illustrate what my desired outcome is, here is a sample of my code. Given the two Lists of string Lists at the top, I would expect CheckOrder() to return true.

```
private List<List<string>> testOrder = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" }, new List<string> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" } };
private List<List<string>> testOrder2 = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" }, new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" } };

public bool CheckOrder() {

        if (testOrder2.Count != testOrder.Count) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testOrder.Count; i++) {

            if (!testOrder2.Contains(testOrder[i])) {
                return false; //here
            } else {
                testOrder2.Remove(testOrder[i]);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

No matter what I try, I can't get CheckOrder() to return anything but false from the commented line. I see other suggestions to use something like SequenceEqual() from the Linq library, but order being unimportant is the whole point of this method I'm trying to write.

Comment: Note that `new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" } != new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" }`, unless `Object.ReferenceEquals(l1, l2);` returns `true`, which it won't for two separate instances of `List<T>`, so you won't get a success from `Contains`.  You'll want to write a custom `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>`  and maybe use a `HashSet<List<string>>` instantiated using that equality comparer.

Comment: I am betting that the line of code... `testOrder2.Contains(testOrder[i])` ... isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725647/listlist-contains-not-working) is a reasonable equivalent to your question, but it does only really mention `.SequenceEqual` which doesn't help you.

Comment: @JohnG I was thinking the same thing after using the debugger and confirming that at least the contents look identical. To me, that piece of code would return true if there was a List identical to testOrder[i] in testOrder2, but are you suggesting something otherwise?

Comment: Look at DiplomacyNotWar’s comments and links. `Contains` doesn’t work as your code attempts to do without extra work on your part… `Contains` will basically ALWAYS return `false` using your code. Inside your current first loop you will need to loop through each list in list2 and compare it with each list in list1 until a match is found. If no match is found, then `false` should be returned. If a match is found, be careful if you decide to “delete” the matching lists... You will have problems deleting an item from the collection you are looping through.

Comment: Is it possible for the same sub-lists to appear multiple times? I mean would `new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" }, new List<string> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" }, new List<String> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" }` be valid?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar in order for CheckOrder() to return true, I would like each List to have exactly one corresponding List in the one its being compared to. That's what I was going for with the first if block in the method.

Comment: _”I would like each List to have exactly one corresponding List in the one its being compared to.”_ … so does that mean that order matters? Is Hotdog/Soda the same as Soda/Hotdog?

Comment: And is it necessary to remove items from `testOrder2`, or do you just do so to ensure that there's only one? It's easier to solve this if you don't have to remove existing items.

Comment: @JohnG 
Say you have these lists: {Burger, Ketchup}, {Burger, Mayo}, {Hot Dog, Mustard}.

And you were comparing it to: {Burger, Ketchup}, {Hot Dog, Mustard}, {Burger, Mayo}.

Then it would return true. The Lists within the Lists are always going to be in the same order just due to the nature of how it's taking input.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar
I suppose it isn't necessary, it just seemed like a clean way of doing it when I thought this would be as simple as I initially had lol

Comment: Consider this… simplify the problem… Hint: create a method that takes two `List<string>` objects and returns true/false if both lists “CONTAIN” the same strings. … `private bool TwoListsContainSameItems(List<string> List1, List<string> List2) {…` Then if order matters, then work on that later… get the “contains” working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll want to make an `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>`. I'll generalise this to `IEqualityComparer<IList<T>>` so that any kind of list can be used. I've also optionally allowed an equality comparer for the individual `T` item values, but it's not necessary here unless you want to make it case insensitive.

The comparer:

```cs
public class ListComparer<TItem> : IEqualityComparer<IList<TItem>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TItem> _itemComparer;

    public ListComparer()
        : this(EqualityComparer<TItem>.Default)
    {

    }

    public ListComparer(IEqualityComparer<TItem> itemComparer)
    {
        _itemComparer = itemComparer;
    }

    // Determine if the two lists have the same content
    public bool Equals(IList<TItem> x, IList<TItem> y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x is null != y is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (x is null && y is null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return x.SequenceEqual(y, _itemComparer);
    }

    // Generate a hashcode from the individual items of the list
    // this is dependent on the order of the items
    // ({A,B} will produce a different value to {B,A})
    public int GetHashCode(IList<TItem> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = 63949;
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                hashCode += _itemComparer.GetHashCode(item);
                hashCode *= 13;
            }
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can simplify your method to this:

```cs
public bool CheckOrder()
{
    // build the comparer for comparing the inner lists
    var innerComparer = new ListComparer<string>();

    // ensure the lists have the same number of items
    if (testOrder2.Count != testOrder.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (var order in testOrder)
    {
        // if an inner list doesn't also exist in testOrder2
        // then return false
        if (!testOrder2.Contains(order, innerComparer))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // all lists were found, so return true
    return true;
}
```

As mentioned in the code comments, this assumes that `{ { "Burger", "Hot Dog" } }` vs `{ { "Hot Dog", "Burger" } }` should return `false` as the inner lists are different.

This doesn't entirely deal with duplicates as you could have `{ { "Burger", "Hot Dog" }, { "Burger", "Hot Dog" } }` in `testOrder` and `{ { "Burger", "Hot Dog" }, { "Chicken", "Coke" } }` in `testOrder2` and it would still work.

Alternatively, you could group and join the data using LINQ, which will check the counts too:

```cs
public bool CheckOrder()
{
    var innerComparer = new ListComparer<string>();
    if (testOrder2.Count != testOrder.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return testOrder
        // group using the list as the key
        .GroupBy(o => o, innerComparer)
        // join the other list (which has been grouped by its lists)
        .Join(
            testOrder2.GroupBy(o => o, innerComparer),
            // use the group key from the first list's groups
            g1 => g1.Key,
            // use the group key from the second list's groups
            g2 => g2.Key,
            // ensure that the counts are equal and produce a bool as a result
            (g1, g2) => g1.Count() == g2.Count(),
            // provide the comparer again so that the keys can be checked for equality
            innerComparer
        )
        // ensure that all returned values are true
        .All(r => r);
}
```

If you want to ensure that there's only ever 1 pair, you could change this line:

`(g1, g2) => g1.Count() == g2.Count()`

to this:

`(g1, g2) => g1.Count() == 1 && g2.Count() == 1`

Comment: I've just put your code into my project and it seems like it's working exactly like I needed it to! I'm a bit confused by what you meant about duplicates not behaving as intended, because when I test all sorts of combinations of orders, it seems to give the desired result each time. Was there a particular test case you had in mind that may be problematic?

Comment: @jared only if you use the first option with `foreach`, and even then only if the overall count was the same. If you're using the LINQ version then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think DiplomacyNotWar has the more efficient way of doing it, as well as some good points you should try to research, but I decided to take a crack at it and here is a rudimentary version that will also get the job done. Please let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps :)

```
    public class Class1
{
    //Renamed testOrder
    public List<List<string>> testOrder1 = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" }, new List<string> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" } };
    public List<List<string>> testOrder2 = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "Hot Dog", "Ketchup" }, new List<string> { "Burger", "Cheese" } };


    public bool CheckOrder()
    {
        //Disqualify if counts vary
        if (testOrder2.Count != testOrder1.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //This is the janky part, converting the lists to strings ☺
            //Create string only working copies of each primary list
            List<string> testOrder1c = new List<string>();
            List<string> testOrder2c = new List<string>();

            //Convert original lists to strings
            foreach (var secondaryList in testOrder1)
            {
                testOrder1c.Add(string.Join(",", secondaryList.ToArray()));
            }
            foreach (var secondaryList in testOrder2)
            {
                testOrder2c.Add(string.Join(",", secondaryList.ToArray()));
            }

            //Create a list of distinct values for each
            List<string> testOrder1d = testOrder1c.Distinct().ToList();
            List<string> testOrder2d = testOrder2c.Distinct().ToList();

            //Disqualify if counts vary
            if(testOrder1d.Count != testOrder2d.Count) { return false; }

            //Disqualify if distinct lists do not match
            testOrder1d.Sort();
            testOrder2d.Sort();
            if(!testOrder1d.SequenceEqual(testOrder2d))
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Create another array to detail the count of each distinct value
            List<int> testOrder1dn = new List<int>();
            List<int> testOrder2dn = new List<int>();

            foreach (var distinctValue in testOrder1d)
            {
                testOrder1dn.Add(testOrder1c.Where(x => x == distinctValue).Count());
            }

            foreach (var distinctValue in testOrder2d)
            {
                testOrder2dn.Add(testOrder2c.Where(x => x == distinctValue).Count());
            }

            //Finally, we will compare these distinct values and their counts to see if they are equivalent.

            //Disqualify if distinct counts do not match
            for (int i = 0; i < testOrder1d.Count; i++)
            {
                if(testOrder1dn[i] != testOrder2dn[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //All distinct lists appear the same number of times in each list:
            return true;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention, this will account for duplicates as well.

Comment: Oh, one more item of note- I realize your title mentions order not mattering. This solution I've provided will necessarily account only for string lists in the same order (i.e. it will not match [burger,cheese] with [cheese,burger]). I'm sure you'd be able to dig deeper and apply another layer of all this for that, but something tells me there is already enough complexity at play for one night :)